# How can I get hunspell to use Australian English?

Tags: language-support, input-language, dictionary, spell-checking

I use a few programs that do spellchecking via `hunspell`, but they seem to check against US English. It'd be beaut if they'd use Australian English (maaaaybe UK English if there's Buckley's of Strine).

My language-related environment variables look right:

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
```

I've fossicked about for any `hunspell-en-au|gb|etc` packages, but they seem to have gone bush in 14.04. What's the fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

G'day mate! There are actually a few `myspell` dictionaries that the Hunspell engine will happily use.  I'm British and I found it frightfully upsetting when [a filthy Canadian dictionary kept overriding my native tongue](https://askubuntu.com/a/184304/449). I don't know why you colonial types can't just learn English rather than trying to break it...

Anyway, you probably just need to install the `myspell-en-au` package.

```
$ apt-cache search myspell-en
myspell-en-au - English_australian dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-gb - English_british dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-us - English_american dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-za - English_southafrican dictionary for myspell
```

Failing that, there is [an OpenOffice addon dictionary](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/AustralianDictionary). You can download this, extract it (rather than installing it) and copy out the `en_AU.dic` and stick it up your `/usr/share/hunspell/dicts/` directory.

For clarification, my `/usr/share/myspell/` directory is full of symlinks to `/usr/share/hunspell/` and `/usr/share/hyphen` (part of the `openoffice.org-hyphenation` package). It seems —at least in terms of packaging dictionary files— the two projects have been merged which sort of makes sense as Hunspell is compatible with the same dictionaries.

Comment: I have all the `myspell-en-*` installed. Is there a way to tell `hunspell` which to use other than the env vars?

Comment: Well you can tell it when you call it (with the -d flag) but I'm guessing you aren't calling it directly. What application are you using?

Comment: I'm using Atom. As far as I can tell, their [spell-check](https://github.com/atom/spell-check) package uses [node-spellchecker](https://github.com/atom/node-spellchecker) (...?) which itself uses [hunspell](https://github.com/atom/node-spellchecker/blob/master/src/spellchecker_hunspell.cc). But I'm not too fluent with Coffeescript, so I'm not 100% sure what's going on there.

Comment: Bah, I just looked at that source again, and it looks like they [hard code the dicts](https://github.com/atom/node-spellchecker/blob/master/src/spellchecker_hunspell.cc#L18)!